# I need to do specific CSS if its outside working hours and if its a bank holiday?

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime

I have a live chat link on my website, which I need to to only show on certain times, which are:

**Monday to Friday 8am to 8pm excluding bank holidays.**

I would like to hide this via time based CSS? or something similar.

I was thinking because I am using WordPress, using a bit of PHP code to implement this CSS?  I think I have to do something with the `strtotime` function.

Comment: CSS has no time based logic. You will have to use PHP.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code or steps you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can via php add/dont add css class which will showing/disabling chat.
Something like this:

Css:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

HTML + PHP

`$bankholidays = [1225, 1226]; //array of dates in format "md" (25.12., 26.12.)`

`<div class="<?php if((date('N') > 5) || (date('H') < 8) || (date('H') > 20) || in_array(date("md"), $bankholidays)) echo 'hidden'; ?>">
    <!-- chat -->
</div>`

Explanation:

```
(date('N') > 5)
date('N') - numeric representation of the day of the week (monday - 1 ..., saturday -6, sunday 7)

(date('H') < 8) || (date('H') > 20)
date('H') - 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros (so hide before 8AM and after 8PM)

in_array(date('md'), $bankholidays)
date("md") - numeric representation of date in year in format mmdd so 0101..1231
```

Comment: Thanks, which part of it is to exclude bank holidays?

Comment: @user3481487 what are bank halidays? is it specific in your country?

Comment: hello, code works great for the hours part thanks. its basically just selected days of the year? can I add that in also? like christmas day, new years day etc.

Comment: @user3481487 i edited my answer, with added bank holidays